# How to unmarshal Go xml?

Tags: xml, go, unmarshalling

I have xml data to unmarshal into slice of strings ["13.64.196.27/32", "13.64.198.19/32"] but getting error "**undefined: Product**"at the very beginning of it all. I have Product struct defined...not sure what it wants from me. See below and play.golang.org/p/Ak6bx3BLwq

```
func main() {
    data := `<products updated="9/1/2017">
<product name="o365">
<addresslist type="IPv4">
<address>13.64.196.27/32</address>
<address>13.64.198.19/32</address>
</addresslist>
</product>
</products>`

    type Azure struct {
        XMLName  xml.Name  `xml:"products"`
        Products []Product `xml:"product"`
    }

    type Product struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"product"`
        Name    string   `xml:"name,attr"`
        List    []List   `xml:"addresslist"`
    }

    type List struct {
        XMLName xml.Name `xml:"addresslist"`
        Type    string   `xml:"type,attr"`
        Address []string `xml:"addressList>address"`
    }

    var products Azure
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &products)
    fmt.PrintLn(products.List.Address)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you should define variables out of function implementations and secondly, you're trying to use `fmt.PrintLn` which doesn't exist.

I've fixed a little, hope it helps:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/xml"
)

type Azure struct {
    XMLName  xml.Name  `xml:"products"`
    Products []Product `xml:"product"`
}

type Product struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"product"`
    Name    string   `xml:"name,attr"`
    List    []List   `xml:"addresslist"`
}

type List struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"addresslist"`
    Type    string   `xml:"type,attr"`
    Address []string `xml:"addressList>address"`
}

func main() {
    data := `<products updated="9/1/2017">
<product name="o365">
<addresslist type="IPv4">
<address>13.64.196.27/32</address>
<address>13.64.198.19/32</address>
</addresslist>
</product>
</products>`

    var products Azure
    xml.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &products)
    fmt.Println(products)
}
```

Comment: Thnx a lot, do you know why it prints empty slice {{ products} [{{ product} o365 [{{ addresslist} IPv4 []}]}]} ? I would expect "13.64.196.27/32", "13.64.198.19/32" inside

Comment: `you should define variables out of function implementations` -> Defining named types inside a function is valid, and sometimes useful especially for unmarshaling stuff IMHO, as you sometimes never need those types anywhere else in the code.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker that's a good idea. I need to do that more often. Some of my code is littered with partial views returned from SQL that serve no purpose elsewhere but to clutter up the package. That said, make sure you don't try to use the same struct Name elsewhere, or things will get really confusing.

Comment: @irom It's a good way for you learn more about GoLang and syntax here [link](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1)

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, in this case, we have the type with nested structs in a function code. For readable code, we can use public / private structs inside of the package and of course for simple JSON unmarshal we can use it but we need to care about the complexity of the next code support

Comment: After  change from "addressList>address" to just "address" it is fine...